# Get Session ID from login via PHP CURL

Tags: php, html, curl, post, authentication

I want to login to gounlimited.to via PHP CURL and I want to get after login the value "sess_id" from this page: https://gounlimited.to/?op=upload_file

I have tried the following code without succcess. I won't login:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://gounlimited.to/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, '');
$arr = array('op' => 'login', 'login' => 'XXXX', 'password' => 'XXXX');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arr); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);      
curl_close($ch);
print_r($output);
```

Comment: Usually (and for all my pages), the session id is an internal identifier and not shared with clients. If this is true for that page too, it is impossible to retrieve the session id.

Comment: you can access only the cookie for example `PHPSESSID` which identify you with actual session id on server side, it's in responce header

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the headers as well, add the following options.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```